# Google App Engine - How does datastore initialization work across sessions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing my first project for GAE, and I'm wondering about how to go about setting up my connection to the datastore.

Currently, I have the following in the header.jsp, which is included in all pages and includes a reference to a Datastore class that I created.

header.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="foo.Datastore"%>

<%
    if (Datastore.getDatastore() == null) {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Datastore.setDatastore(datastore);
    }
%>
```

Datastore.java:

```
public class Datastore {
    private static DatastoreService ds;

    public static DatastoreService getDatastore() {
        return ds;
    }
    public static void setDatastore(DatastoreService d) {
        ds = d;
    }
}
```

Will this connect me to the SAME datastore every time I use the application? If so, can you explain how this works? How does `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()` know which datastore to connect to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify which datastore to connect to, because there is only one datastore for each application.